# Error loading ASGI app. Attribute "app" not found in module "main"

Tags: python, fastapi

I installed FASTAPI and was running below mentioned code

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
    
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

and am getting below mentioned error in console on executing the file

```
(venv) D:\FASTAPI>uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['D:\\FASTAPI']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [7900] using watchgod
ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Attribute "app" not found in module "main".
```

I really appreciate any recommendations or suggestions

Comment: In what file have you saved the python code? Is it stored in the `d:\FASTAPI` directory?

Comment: the problem is the address of your python interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

> First look the project tree. The **main.py** file is under ***app*** directory.

In my project like this:

```
fastapi 
   -> app
      -> main.py
```

[image: My project folder tree]

Copy codes to **main.py**:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Run the server:

```
uvicorn app.main:app --reload
```

But if you try to run this server like:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

This will cause the error:

```
Error loading ASGI app. Attribute "app" not found in module "main"
```

Hope you understood. Run and enjoy coding....

Comment: '''uvicorn app.main:app --reload''' - works for me

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: Make sure you have set VS Studio Code to "autosave". If updated code not saved, interpreter will not allow app startup.

Comment: Thank you! I was going mad haha :)

Answer (score 2):

It work like this: `uvicorn root-file-name:root-function-in-the-file --reload`

Just put the name of the root function:

```
def root():
 print('works')
```

`uvicorn main:root --reload`

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same issue.

here is the solution

Go to main.py (file created in the file folder)

--> Paste the piece of code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
  return {"Hello": "World"}
```

---> right click main.py

-------> Select 'Run python file in terminal'

--> Now run the script : uvicorn main:app

--> It'll work

Answer (score -1):

your folder should be in C/:
name src and then create main.py[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om6rP.png)